# what type of variables can i put in the dependency array of all hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been working with react for quite some time and i still somehow wonder what type of opjects can i put inside the dependecy array of react hooks (doesnt matter what hook is it), how exactly is react comparing single items inside the dependecy array and should i parse large objects like lists or nested js objects?

for example here is a object the i want useCallback to change whenever a list inside it changes:

```
function App(){
    const [array,setArray] = useState([{first:'jimmy',last:'willow'}]);
    const someCallback = useCalback(()=>{
        window.alert(JSON.stringify(array))
    }, [array]) // here I wonder what should I usually put?  just the array or should I parse it  to string to something like that....

// ... somthing here changes the state
    return array.map(({first,last})=><div onClick={someCallback}>{first} , {last} </div>)
}
```

Comment: array is correct, the dependency is the variable that changes, and the variable that you require in useCallback to get the final value you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put absolutely anything inside the dependency array, keeping in mind that comparison is performed based on `Object.is`. If any of the values are different, it's considered a change.

So, the dependency array can contain anything: normal values like strings and booleans, or `null`, or even functions and anything else you can think of.

In this particular case, since `setArray` (if you ever change the array) will be called with a *new array*, the new value in the stateful `array` variable will be `!==` to the prior value in that variable, resulting in the `useCallback` constructing the callback again. So having `[array]` for the dependency array should be just fine, as long as you're following React rules normally and not mutating state.

Comment: Is there any documentation that says that is fine to put anything?  I want to manipulate my depencies like so `dependencies.map(useDeepCompareMemoize)` 

Would that be a problem?

Comment: The docs say "useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed", and say that [they use `Object.is`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) when comparing values. Any value that can be compared to another value (in other words: anything) is fine. Mapping through `useDeepCompareMemoize` sounds good, though it'd be nicer for the dependencies to not change to begin with IMO.